# reThinkDB join / where exists equivalent too slow

Tags: node.js, join, rethinkdb

I am doing something very similar to the last `SELECT` example in the [reThinkDB SQL cheatsheet](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/javascript/) :

SQL :

```
SELECT *
  FROM posts
  WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM users
     WHERE posts.author_id
         = users.id)
```

Rethink :

```
r.table("posts")
  .filter(function (post) {
    return r.table("users")
      .filter(function (user) {
        return user("id").eq(post("authorId"))
      }).count().gt(0)
    })
```

Here is the exact query I am doing (although I don't think it matters) :

```
// Sample data :
// app table :
// [{id : 123, city : 'abc' }, { id : 234 }, ...]

// weather table :
// [{id : 1, city : 'abc', data : 'some data' }, { id : 2 }, ...]

// ex. rWeather(123) should return [{id : 1, city : 'abc', data : 'some data' }]
// by finding the city 'abc', first in the app table, then in the weather table

/**
 * Returns the weather for a given app
 */
export function rWeather (id) {

    var appCity = function(weather) {
        return r.db('gfi')
            .table('app')
            .withFields(['city'])
            .filter(function (app) {
                return app('id').eq(weather('appId'));
            });
    };

    return r.db('gfi')
        .table('weather')
        .filter(function(weather) {
            return  appCity(weather).count().gt(0);
        });
}
```

So the question is : how do I speed this up ?

Should I change the form of my query ? Should I add indexes (where) ?

**Note :** I cannot profile it in the web interface, the query just runs for a long time.

Comment: What is your expected outcome here? Am I understanding correctly you want all posts that have an associated `user_id` and that user exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code comment doesn't match with your code. In your code, it seems like you are joining using `appId` field on `weather` table. and inside `rWeather`, you don't use variable `id`...

So I will re-write it to match your comment

> // ex. rWeather(123) should return [{id : 1, city : 'abc', data :
>   'some data' }] // by finding the city 'abc', first in the app table,
>   then in the weather table

Create an index:

```
r.table('weather').indexCreate('city')
```

Here is a function:

```
export function rWeather (id) {

  return r.db('gfi')
        .table('app').get(id).do(function(app) {
          return r.table('weather').getAll(app('city').default(''), {index: 'city'})
        })

 }
```